# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, android

Tenho um serviço na Web que valida os usuários do aplicativo que roda no Android. Em caso positivo o sistema devolve um JSON com a informação que esta ok e a qual base de dados esse usuário tem acesso.

Passo um JSON simples ao serviço:

```
{ 
    "email":"usuario@abc.com.br",
    "senha":"12456"
}
```

Esta acontecendo que ao chamar o serviço através do WIFI funciona como esperado,
porém se eu chamo através do 4G recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Olhando o log do serviço verifico que a requisição sequer chega no servidor.

Alguém já passou por isso e pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não mostra esforço. Estou pesquisando desde as 8:30 da manhã. Só depois tive a ideia de perguntar aos senhores. tsc...tsc..

Comment: Aliás até já achei a solução e poderia ter excluído a pergunta, mas, pensei que poderia ser útil para mais alguém, afinal é um problema chato e sem uma solução aparente. Mas o que faz a comunidade? Negativa a pergunta. É uma lástima.

Answer (score 0):

Você adicionou a permição de acessar a internet ao seu app?

Permissões:

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/ >

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/ >

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/ >

Essas permissões deve ser colocadas na classe AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Sim. Como eu disse com o WIFI acessa normalmente.

Comment: veja isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406275/getting-error-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset

Comment: Obrigado João pela atenção. Eu já tinha visto esse link, mas também não é isso. O código no WebService também não tem problemas. Por dois motivos: com o WIFI funciona perfeitamente e com o 4G ela sequer chega no servidor. Porém eu sei que é o servidor que  esta resetando porque se eu deixo o serviço parado dá erro de TIMEOUT e se eu rodo o serviço ele não aceita conexões através do 4G.

Comment: Eu tenho um código que usa Json. Vou deixar disponível pra vc baixar e comparar. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kheVh9bjc4oJ0NcJyyEp6h59CzDCEOwn

Comment: Não sei não, mas isso está com cara de infraestrutura. Não tem alguma restrição no Firewall do Servidor, ou algum bloqueio no anti-vírus e etc.? Você colocou log no WebService, certo?! Teria que monitorar o Servidor com o Wireshark para ver se a requisição está chegando e aonde está sendo sendo enviada pelo Firewall. Já tive problemas com conexões Socket e era esse o problema.

Comment: Obrigado @RaquelPinheiro. Baixei o programa Wireshark, vou monitorar para ver o que chega e se chega.